# How do I get number of common numbers in an array record in Mysql?

Tags: php

How do I get mode of an array record in Mysql?
        
i.e: 1,2,3,4,5    ,    1,3,5
I would like to get out of the table user_friends to get which friends these friends have in common, in this case, 1,3,5. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you have a table

```
user | friend
-------------
6    | 1
6    | 2
6    | 3
6    | 4
6    | 5
7    | 1
7    | 3
7    | 5
```

then you can do

```
SELECT *
FROM friends f1
JOIN friends f2 USING (friend)
WHERE f1.user = 6
  AND f2.user = 7
```

and you will get

```
user | friend | user
--------------------
6    | 1      | 7
6    | 3      | 7
6    | 5      | 7
```